# Do not delete a raw pointer that is not an owner<T> (i.11)

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I was trying to experiment the rules of Five / Three / Zero. When Compiling my program I got a warning `C26401`saying that I have to not delete pointer that I don't own and this in the line `delete[] pChar_;` in the destructor function.

I agree that I have issue there specially when calling `move ctor`, when I apply `std::swap` when calling  to the source object.

So how could I correct this issue ?

***Edit***:  As suggested in comment, I may use std::string (Good) but I wanna know how to fix the issue without modifying the types let's say to learn that :)

```
using namespace std;

struct A
{

  A();
  A(int Int, const char* pChar);

  A(const A& rhs);
  A& operator=(A rhs);

  A(A&& rhs);

  ~A();

  void swap(A& rhs);
  int Int_ = 0;
  char *pChar_ = nullptr;
};

A::~A()
{
    std::cout << "----DTOR----" << std::endl;

    if (pChar_ != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] pChar_;
        pChar_ = nullptr;
    }
}

A::A(int Int, const char* pChar) :
     Int_(Int), pChar_(new char[strlen(pChar) + 1])
{
    strncpy_s(pChar_, strlen(pChar) + 1, pChar, _TRUNCATE);
}

A::A(const A& rhs) : A(rhs.Int_, rhs.pChar_) {}

A& A::operator=(A rhs)
{   
    swap(rhs);
    return *this;
}

A::A(A&& rhs)
{
    swap(rhs);
}

void A::swap(A& rhs)    
{
    std::swap(this->Int_, rhs.Int_);
    std::swap(this->pChar_, rhs.pChar_);
}

int main()
{
    A v1{ 1, "Hello" }; 
    {
        A v3{ std::move(v1) };
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace your `char*` with `std::string` and you can go back to Rule of Zero.

Comment: @CoryKramer : yes this what I think to use, but I would like to know if there is way to fix that without using std::string, just to learn how fix such situations.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem with the code.  FWIW the `if (pChar_ != nullptr)` check is unneeded as `delete` on a `nullptr` is a non-op

Comment: I vaguely recall some `owner<Ptr>` tag in the GSL.

Comment: @chris : nice I read that in the guideline but the example showed is sth like owner<X*> for a function returning a pointer but this is not my case, could you exlplain how could I use this Owner !?!

Comment: You would at least need to mark the pointer doing the owning (the one you delete). I don't know about parameters or anything. (edit: Never mind, it wouldn't apply to parameters if you're not seizing ownership anyway.)

Comment: unrelated: You've a perfect example here of [the toxicity of `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) by using your own `swap` and `std::swap`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have copy of VS handy that can reproduce your warning but it seems to me that the warning is from the [CPP Code Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines), specifically [I.11: Never transfer ownership by a raw pointer (T*) or reference (T&)](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i11-never-transfer-ownership-by-a-raw-pointer-t-or-reference-t):

> Enforcement
>
> - (Simple) Warn on delete of a raw pointer that is not an `owner<T>`. Suggest use of standard-library resource handle or use of `owner<T>`.

So the solution is to use `gsl::owner<char *> pChar_ = nullptr;`. Please note that `gsl::owner` is nothing more than an annotation to help readers of code (humans or tools) and won't magically make your code safe.

As far as I can see your code looks ok.

---

One issue I have is the ctor:

```
A(int Int, const char* pChar) :
    Int_(Int), pChar_(new char[strlen(pChar) + 1])
{
    strncpy_s(pChar_, strlen(pChar) + 1, pChar, _TRUNCATE);
}
```

This is unsafe code disguised as safe. `strncpy_s` gives you a sense of safety. But in reality it does absolutely nothing (for safety that is) in your code. Because if there is a problem with `pChar` (e.g. it doesn't point to a null terminated string) then `strlen` will fail first. So either say what every std function says: `pChar` shall be a valid pointer to a null-termiated string and count as UB otherwise, or guard at `strlen`. Once you guard at strlen then `strcpy` is enough.

Also you don't check that `Int` is equal to `strlen`. They should be.